# Maven: Run Test On the JAR

Tags: maven, automated-tests, integration-testing

I've coded my own `ApplicationListener` for Spring-Boot that looks for files on the classpath. When running the test in Maven it looks for files in the filesystem as the JAR doesn't exist yet. That's fine and is a good test as it covers running the final application from within an IDE.

However, I also want to test my class when it's run inside a JAR (not necessarily as a repackaged Spring-Boot JAR) to see if it grabs the files inside the JAR. The tests-JAR contains all those files I want to read so theoretically it's all ready.

So how do I set this up with Maven? There's just one test I want to run after the JAR was built, all other tests are run as tests and integration-tests in the common lifecycle-phase (well, I have to filter out that one test for those phases somehow, too).

Comment: The integration test phases pre-integration-test, integration-test and post-integration-test are after the packaging ... So what is the real problem ? And what purpose has an application listener to look for files on classpath? What kind of files?

Comment: @khmarbaise the problem is that the integration tests are run with the class-files in the filesystem and not the classes in the JAR. I want the test to be run from the JAR. The files are read and become properties to be used by Spring as part of externalised configuration.

Comment: An externalised configuration in Spring Boot sounds wrong to be honest. Why not using spring-profiles etc. which are already provided by Spring boot.. Can you create an example project of what you like to do? ...

Comment: @khmarbaise This project isn't a one-liner so I can't come up with a small sample project. Other than that profiles make no sense here. I'm collecting properties and that isn't based on profiles. This question is about tests.